# Git revert temporarily

Tags: git, revert

I have a situation where I accidentally pushed an incomplete commit `C1` to the remote branch. Now I want to revert the remote branch but **temporarily**, so that I can still work on the commit `C1` locally and amend some more changes to it.

I did,

```
git revert C1
```

Which created a commit with undo changes and I pushed it to remote branch as another commit `C2`. Done.

But how can I start working on the commit `C1` that is reverted? should I checkout that specific commit `C1`? If I do so, `git status` shows detached header in my local repo.

Comment: Why not just revert the commit on the remote branch, finish your changes locally, the commit + push the whole thing? Once a commit is made, it cannot really be changed; an amended commit is actually a rebase, which creates new commits with different hashes than the pre-amend commits.

Comment: Thanks, I went with @Charles Durham's answer. which is quite similar to your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new branch off `C1` and then work from there. Then when you're done with your additions to `C1` merge it back into your default branch.

`git checkout C1 & git checkout -b newC1BranchName`

Comment: Thanks this works! The thing I was missing was that there was no local branch for that detached header. but this resolves that issue :)